# Inserir multiplos itens Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, inserir

Tenho o seguinte método para adicionar dados docliente

```
public void Alterar(CLIENTE Cliente)
{
    using (Entity.DominioEntity db = new Entity.DominioEntity())
    {
        //Alterar/Adicionar Telefone
        foreach (var item in Cliente.TELEFONE)
        {
            if (item.Codigo == 0)
                db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Added;

            else
                db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        //Deletar Telefones
        List<int> delItemTelefone = new List<int>();
        foreach (var item in Cliente.TELEFONE)
        {
            ///Se o codigo = zero e Deletar = true -> não faz nada.
            if (item.Deletar == true)
                delItemTelefone.Add(item.Codigo);
        }

        foreach (var item in delItemTelefone)
        {
            db.Entry(cliente.TELEFONE.Single(t => t.Codigo == item)).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        }

        db.CLIENTE.Attach(Cliente);
        db.Entry(Cliente).State = EntityState.Modified;

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Funciona sem problemas, mas quando eu vou salvar um cliente que adicionei dois telefones novos da o seguinte erro:

> Attaching an entity of type 'Dominio.Entity.TELEFONE' failed because
>   another entity of the same type already has the same primary key
>   value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the
>   state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the
>   graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities
>   are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In
>   this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track
>   the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or
>   'Modified' as appropriate.

Sei que o problema é que quando inseri os telefones o campa da chave primaria deles são "0", mas como resolver isso?

Comment: Já viu isto? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework

Comment: Vi mas não entendi.

Answer (score 0):

Poderia mudar o campo da chave primária? Por exemplo, usar um identity para gerar auto incremento na key.

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Int32 Id { get; set; }
```